# Google BigQuery - To match a specific word in a column with a text in another column in different Tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I’m trying to match different information from different tables in `SQL`.

I have 2 tables.
Table1 with 1 column `words` that include words like love, passion, job... And Table2 with 1 column `text` that includes a fragment of a News.

I am using Big Query in Google Cloud Platform and I need a Query to match which `words` are in the `text`

I have tried this query, but it doesn't work

```
SELECT b.word
    ,a.text
FROM Table1 b
INNER JOIN Table2 a ON ' '+ b.word + ' ' LIKE '% ' + a.text + ' %';
```

I have this Information
[Information in the tables]

And I want to get this
[Result expected]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

As you've missed provide readable input/output - I just used text of your post to make up dummy data

Hope below example shows you right way to go with

```
#standardSQL
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT 'love' AS word UNION ALL
  SELECT 'passion' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'job' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'cloud'
), table2 AS (
  SELECT '''I’m trying to match different information from different tables in SQL.''' text UNION ALL
  SELECT '''I have 2 tables. Table1 with 1 column “words” that iclude words like love, passion, job... And Table2 with 1 column “text” that include a fragment of a News.''' UNION ALL
  SELECT '''I am using Big Query in Google Cloud Platform and I need a Query to match which “words” are in the “text”''' UNION ALL
  SELECT '''I have tried this query, but it doesn't work''' UNION ALL
  SELECT '''SELECT b.word ,a.text FROM Table1 b INNER JOIN Table2 a ON ' '+ b.word + ' ' LIKE '% ' + a.text + ' %';''' UNION ALL
  SELECT '''I have this Information [Information in the tables]''' UNION ALL
  SELECT '''And I want to get this [Result expected]''' UNION ALL
  SELECT '''Thanks for your help!''' 
)
SELECT word, text
FROM table1 b
JOIN table2 a ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, CONCAT(r'(?i)\b', word, r'\b'))
-- ORDER BY text, word
```

see more about [regular expression syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried and it doesn’t work to me. I tried in both Mysql and Google Big Query and I get this answer.  Mysql: Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat'.
Google Big Query - Error: 4.65 - 4.100: Unrecognized function regexp_contains
Do I have to change anything? Thanks!

Comment: why you would even tried it in MySQL - this is clearly stated to be for `BigQuery` and specifically for `Standard SQL` - juts copy paste above into your BQ UI, make sure you have enabled Standard SQL and run it! You can remove whole `WITH` statement to run it for your specific tables - but make sure you replaced table1 and table2 with fully qualified path like \`project.dataset.table\`

Comment: It Works! The only problem is that the Query match the characters not de whole word. For example, if I have “bee” as a word this match with the text because there’s the word “been”. Should I open another Question?

Comment: thanks for trying :o) and making it work. no need for new question - it is definitely clear that you were asking for matching word - see updated answer - the change is in ON clouse

Answer (score 0):

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  Table1 AS (
  SELECT
    "a" AS word
  UNION ALL (
    SELECT
      "b" AS word)),
  Table2 AS (
  SELECT
    "abc" AS text
  UNION ALL (
    SELECT
      "acn" AS text))
SELECT
  a.word,
  b.text
FROM
  Table1 a
JOIN
  Table2 b
ON
  b.text LIKE CONCAT('%',a.word,'%')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried and it doesn’t work to me. I tried in both Mysql and Google Big Query and I get this answer.  Mysql: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ b.word + '%'' at line 3.
Google Big Query - Error: Encountered " <ID> "a "" at line 3, column 42. Was expecting: <EOF>
Do I have to change anything? Thanks!

Comment: I edited the SQL to the one that produced correct results for me. Make sure to use standard SQL: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql . The "#standardSQL" line on top of the query is one of the ways to do this. You can use REGEXP_CONTAINS instead of LIKE as in the second example, but I personally find the LIKE syntax more readable 
 in simple cases like this.

Comment: It Works! Thanks for the reference. The only problem is that the Query match the characters not de whole word. For example, if I have “bee” as a word this match with the text because there’s the word “been”. Should I open another Question?

Comment: I see. If a word can be separated from the text in different ways (whitespace, coma etc) it's easier to use regexp with the '\b' world boundary symbol, as the other answer suggests. If it's always whitespaces, you can do b.text LIKE CONCAT('% ',a.word,' %')